# Able to store image to a pat but unable to access it using `File` for Thumbnail Creation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-image, android-file, android-thumbnail

I am able to store an image and display it ImageView using the same `filePath` but get an error when trying to access it for thumbnail creation using `ThumbnailUtils`

I have a fragment, That captures the image using `ActivityResultContract`

```kotlin
class TakePictureWithUriReturnContract : ActivityResultContract<Uri, Pair<Boolean, Uri>>() {
    private lateinit var imageUri: Uri

    @CallSuper
    override fun createIntent(context: Context, input: Uri): Intent {
        imageUri = input
        return Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, input)
    }

    override fun getSynchronousResult(
        context: Context,
        input: Uri
    ): SynchronousResult<Pair<Boolean, Uri>>? = null

    @Suppress("AutoBoxing")
    override fun parseResult(resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?): Pair<Boolean, Uri> {
        return (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) to imageUri
    }
}
```

The above mentioned code is used to handle the contract

```kotlin
val photoFile = File.createTempFile(
            "IMG_",
            ".jpg",
            requireContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        )

        val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            requireContext(),
            "${requireContext().packageName}.fileprovider",
            photoFile
        )

        sampleActivityRes.launch(uri)
```

This method is used to launch the Contract and I am able to get the URI successfully.

I am also able to view the image by setting it to `ImageView`.

But when I try to access it for thumbnail creation using

```kotlin
private fun generateImageThumbnail(imagePath: String): Bitmap {
        val THUMB_SIZE = 64

        val cancellationToken = CancellationSignal()


        return ThumbnailUtils.createImageThumbnail(
            File(imagePath),
            Size(THUMB_SIZE, THUMB_SIZE),
            cancellationToken
        )
    }
```

I get `java.io.FileNotFoundException` exception.

My file_paths.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="my_images"
        path="Android/data/com.example.name/files/Pictures" />
    <external-path
        name="external"
        path="." />
    <external-files-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <cache-path
        name="cache"
        path="." />
    <external-cache-path
        name="external_cache"
        path="." />
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />
    <files-path
        name="images"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

Android Manifest

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" />

    <application
        android:name=".TripMemoryApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TripMemory"
        tools:targetApi="31">

        <provider
            android:name="com.android.tripmemory.utils.MyFileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.android.tripmemory.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
        <!--
             TODO: Before you run your application, you need a Google Maps API key.

             To get one, follow the directions here:

                https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key

             Once you have your API key (it starts with "AIza"), define a new property in your
             project's local.properties file (e.g. MAPS_API_KEY=Aiza...), and replace the
             "YOUR_API_KEY" string in this file with "${MAPS_API_KEY}".
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAriNq0SqdYMLgBkShF7E0xaPrGpMf4YZ8" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

sampleResActivity

```kotlin
val sampleActivityRes = registerForActivityResult(
        TakePictureWithUriReturnContract()
    ) { (isSuccess, imageURI) ->
        if (isSuccess) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Image URI: $imageURI")
            binding.sampleImage.bringToFront()
            binding.sampleImage.setImageURI(imageURI)

            navigateToImagePreview(
                imageURI = imageURI.toString(),
                pathId = viewModel.pathInstance.id
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note that this approach of using a `lateinit var imageUri: Uri` is going to fail on many, many devices due to low memory (as the Camera app is often enough to push every other app out of memory) or any device if the user rotates their device while the camera is up (thus causing your activity to go through a config change, destroying your   contract instance). That's why `ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture` is written as it is and why [the docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#launch) specifically mention saving that additional state separately.

Comment: But the real question is: why are you using the `Uri` you send to the Camera app and not the `File` that you already have access to? Going through the Uri is never going to work with `File` based APIs

Comment: `sampleActivityRes.launch(uri)` You did not show how you declared sampleActivityRes. Further we dont know what you used as imagePath..

Comment: `also able to view the image by setting it to ImageView.` Unclear what you did. Did you use the uri? The file path? Or what? The image? How?

Comment: `file_paths.xml` It is unclear why you post all your FileProvider stuff as you do not use it at generating a thumbnail. Well not that i see you do.

Comment: @Ianhanniballake What do you mean by "Going through Uri is never going to work with `File` based APIs "

Comment: @blackapps added `sampleRes` to the question

Also I posted `file_paths.xml` because it is used in `createTempFile`

Comment: `imagePath` is the uri from the `ActivityResultContract` converted to string @blackapps

Comment: That is not a path but a scheme. So File(imagePath) would be File("content://.....")? Well that will not go. You cannot use a content scheme with the File class. You should use photoFile instead.

Comment: @blackapps thanks, if File("content://...") is a schema, What would be the URI for the file.

Comment: You do not need an Uri to begin with. `if File("content://...") is a schema,` No. "content://...." is a content scheme. Which cannot be used for the File class as the File class expects a file path. Wrong question.  I already told you to replace `File(imagePath),` by `photoFile,`. ( the one from val photoFile = File.crea.....).

Comment: @blackapps thanks, But I am actually passing the URI in fragment directions as you can see on sampleResActivity, I am unable to pass the entire `File` object in directions, I am hoping it will work if I pass the absolute path of the file

Comment: Yes then it will work. And you have that path in photoFile like photoFile.getAbsolutePath().

Comment: @blackapps and it worked , Thanks again for helping. I am pretty new to android. Thanks for helping me to work it out

Comment: Reread the second comment of @ianhanniballake as already there it was told you to use your file path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @blackapps

The issue was that the `imagePath` in `generateImageThumbnail` was a `Schema` instead of being an `URI`/ `path`.

It would work if we pass the `absolutePath` of the file

so the change would be calling `generateImageThumbnail(photoFile.absolutePath)` with the absolute path of the File

```kotlin
val photoFile = File.createTempFile(
            "IMG_",
            ".jpg",
            requireContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        )

generateImageThumbnail(photoFile.absolutePath)
```